# comparing two text files' contents using PowerShell

Tags: file, powershell, compare

I am having two text files having comma separated data.I want to compare and find out the difference between these two files' content.
How to do this with using PowerShell. 
I am getting the rows count as per below code:

```
$rows = Get-Content "D:\FCA\FCA_node_final.txt" 
$rows.count

$rows = Get-Content "D:\FCA\FCA.txt" 
$rows.count
```

here am getting the count 358 and 379 i want to get the remaining 21 rows.
   here is the format of file :

Pre-Validation/MIS,MIS,MIS
   Pre-Validation/MIS/Reports,Reports,Reports
   Pre-Validation/PBGSBLC,PBGSBLC,PBG/SBLC
   /PBGSBLC/SBLCBGdetails,SBLCBGdetails,SBLC/BG details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Compare-Object cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849941.aspx):

```powershell
Compare-Object -referenceobject $(get-content "D:\FCA\FCA_node_final.txt") -differenceobject $(get-content "D:\FCA\FCA.txt")
```

Comment: I am having a  comma separated lines  in this text file.So I need to compare against next lines of tow  files. i mean, if the  first file has 10 rows and second file has 15 rows, i need to get the difference is 5.And can I get the these rows printed?

Comment: you can use something like $reference = (get-content "D:\FCA\FCA_node_final.txt") -split ','  and do that for the diffrence object to and then use the compare-object cmdlet